# How to set Proxy Settings when installing Oracle 11g on Windows 7 Ultimate Edition?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have downloaded the file - "win32_11gR2_database_1of2.zip" from oracle site.

While installing Oracle 11g, I find this window in the first place:

[image]

What to do?

What values should I put on the dialog box?

Where can I get the related info very concisely?

[image]

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment? There may be a firewall which is only allowing HTTP traffic to certain sites or statefully inspecting HTTP headers such as User-Agent and only allowing your corporate-installed browser.

Comment: No I am at my home. I am using broadband internet. Is it possible that my IP blocked this site? If yes, then how am I able to download the Oracle software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly that you are entering an email address into the installer to receive information about updates. However this functionality will only work correctly if you also have a valid Oracle Support account.

Since you are in a home environment, I would leave the email address empty. The installer should then proceed without generating any HTTP requests to Oracle's servers.

You will however also have to download win32_11gR2_database_2of2.zip separately and unzip that into the same directory.